# Custom Drag Preview for touch screens with [dnd-multi-backend] or [TouchBackend]+[HTML5Backend]+[Modernizr]?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, drag-and-drop, modernizr, react-dnd

on the **dnd-multi-backend** library, there are instructions with such text:

> Since native Drag-n-Drop is not currently supported in touch devices. A custom **DragPreview** is required. Check out the *example* for a sample implementation.

But a link to example doesn't work.
Does anyone has got an example of how to add a 'ghost' preview when dragging an element on touch devices?

P.S. On laptops Preview works. Preview option in `HTML5toTouch` is set to `true`.

1) When using **dnd-multi-backend** dnd on laptops and touch devices works but **no preview on touch devices** :

```
import MultiBackend, { TouchTransition } from 'react-dnd-multi-backend';
import TouchBackend from 'react-dnd-touch-backend';
import HTML5Backend from 'react-dnd-html5-backend';

    const HTML5toTouch = {
  backends: [
    {
      backend: HTML5Backend,
    },
    {
      backend: TouchBackend({
        enableMouseEvents: true,
        enableTouchEvents: true,
        touchSlop: 20,
      }), // Note that you can call your backends with options
      preview: true,
      transition: TouchTransition,
    },
  ],
};

export default DragDropContext(MultiBackend(HTML5toTouch))(MyPage);
```

2) When using **[TouchBackend]+[HTML5Backend]+[Modernizr]** :
With such code drag and drop on **touch devices don't work**:

```
export default DragDropContext(
  Modernizr.touchevents ? TouchBackend : HTML5Backend,
)(MyPage);
```

3) I tried to add **Preview** but it does **not track when dragging**:

```
import MultiBackend, {
  TouchTransition,
  Preview,
} from 'react-dnd-multi-backend';

  const generatePreview = (object) => (
        <div style={{ backgroundColor: 'red' }}>Generated</div>
      );
<Preview generator={generatePreview} />
```

Answer (score 2):

Be sure to include the style prop in your generated `<div>`. If you don't, your preview won't move around the page. It includes style stuff that updates as the item is dragged.

So your code would be updated to:

```
const generatePreview = (type, item, style) => (
       return <div style={style}>Generated</div>;
  );
<Preview generator={generatePreview} />
```

I referred to a few files in the repo: [preview/examples/App.js](https://github.com/LouisBrunner/dnd-multi-backend/blob/9ff97cdca3e504dc1360b4786ea9dc9f8dd7d847/packages/react-dnd-preview/examples/App.js) and [react-dnd-preview/src/index.js](https://github.com/LouisBrunner/dnd-multi-backend/blob/b0647343892d56857d095882ddeabd0218c06983/packages/react-dnd-preview/src/index.js)